# Oracle ORA-14400 Error.

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I would like to ask you for help.

Currently, I am working to turn unpartitioned database to partitioned, so somewhen along the line I do `INSERT INTO SELECT` query, when the ORA-14400 appears.

TABLE_1 is partitioned by  LIST and subpartioned by RANGE. More specifically,

```
PARTITION         HIGH VALUE
FIRST             'D', 'T'
    FIRST_1       TO_DATE(' 2017-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
    FIRST_2       TO_DATE(' 2017-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
    FIRST_3       TO_DATE(' 2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
    FIRST_4       TO_DATE(' 2018-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
    FIRST_5       TO_DATE(' 2018-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
    FIRST_6       MAXVALUE
SECOND            DEFAULT
    SECOND_1      MAXVALUE
```

And then I have got TABLE_2 and TABLE_3 that are referencing TABLE_1 via Foreign Key and are partitioned by reference to TABLE_1

I managed to load TABLE_1 and TABLE_2 with `INSERT INTO SELECT` just fine, but TABLE_3 is giving me error above.

From my point of view, I have both Partitions and Subpartitions covered for all valid entries. If the partition key is not D or T it falls to default and all dates are accounted for.

Table contains too much data to manually check through for outlining entry.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have some NULL values on partition keys?

Comment: That would be wierd, right? I have all parents loaded in table1 already and table3 is partitioned by reference, so no partition key by itself (other than the FK). Table1 already is done, partitioned and filled, therefore its partition key is valid. Table3 is partitioned by FK reference, if I had attempted to insert a value that is not present in Table1, I suppose I would get constraint violation for attempting to transfer a child record without its parent, isn't that right?

Comment: You may post the DDL of the tables 1 and 3 to be more clear, but IMO this is not expected behaviour, so you should open a SR with Oracle. To localize the ugly record use either PL/SQL loop inserting row by row or if not feasible the logarithmic search inserting repeatedly half of records. Aparently the reference partitioning with composite paritioning is a special case, as the parent table is subpartitioned, but the child table is partitioned...